# JavaMail Session Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jakarta-mail

Good evening everyone,

I am working on a **jakarta ee** project for a few days but I am stuck.

Indeed, I created a **JavaMail Session** that I use in my project to send Mail at the start and stop of my web application but I wanted to create a class to test if it works first here is the code :

```
package sn.edu.ugb.ipsl.appventevelo;


import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.annotation.Resource;
import jakarta.ejb.Singleton;
import jakarta.ejb.Startup;
import jakarta.mail.Message;
import jakarta.mail.MessagingException;
import jakarta.mail.Session;
import jakarta.mail.Transport;
import jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class EmailSender {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        EnvoyerEmail("mouhamedn842@gmail.com", "Mail de Test", "Eh bien! Suis le meilleur");
    }

    @Resource(lookup = "mail/AppVenteVeloMailSession")
    private Session session;

    public void EnvoyerEmail(String to, String objet, String contenu)  {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject(objet);
            message.setText(contenu);

            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("###### Message envoyé avec succés");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("######## Erreur d'envoi!");
        }
    }

}
```

But when I start my application server it generates an error. Here are the log details

```
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.mail.Provider: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1244)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
    at jakarta.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:987)
    at jakarta.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:273)
    at jakarta.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.resources.mail.naming.MailNamingObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(MailNamingObjectFactory.java:58)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:342)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:877)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:834)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:257)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.naming.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.api.ResourceProxy.create(ResourceProxy.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:827)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:257)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiNamingObjectFactory.java:74)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiInitializationNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiInitializationNamingObjectFactory.java:90)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:603)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lambda$lookup$0(JavaURLContext.java:153)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookupOrCollectException(JavaURLContext.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:153)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:818)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:269)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:413)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:413)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:493)
    ... 56 more

[2023-08-21T23:13:18.527542Z] [GF 7.0.5] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [jakarta.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=48 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
jakarta.ejb.EJBException: jakarta.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton EmailSender
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:622)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:362)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:97)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.mail.Provider: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1244)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
    at jakarta.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:987)
    at jakarta.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:273)
    at jakarta.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.resources.mail.naming.MailNamingObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(MailNamingObjectFactory.java:58)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:342)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:877)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:834)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:257)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.naming.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.api.ResourceProxy.create(ResourceProxy.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:827)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:257)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiNamingObjectFactory.java:74)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiInitializationNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiInitializationNamingObjectFactory.java:90)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:603)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lambda$lookup$0(JavaURLContext.java:153)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookupOrCollectException(JavaURLContext.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:153)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:818)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:269)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:413)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:413)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:493)
    ... 56 more

    [2023-08-21T23:13:18.530532Z] [GF 7.0.5] [SEVERE] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=48 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception while loading the app]]
    
    [2023-08-21T23:13:18.648764Z] [GF 7.0.5] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00192] [jakarta.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=48 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Undeployment failed for context /AppVenteVelo-1.0-SNAPSHOT]]
    
    [2023-08-21T23:13:18.699150Z] [GF 7.0.5] [SEVERE] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=48 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception while loading the app : jakarta.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton EmailSender
    jakarta.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton EmailSender
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:450)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:620)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:362)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:195)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:156)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:134)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:97)
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.mail.Provider: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1244)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
        at jakarta.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:987)
        at jakarta.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:273)
        at jakarta.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:309)
        at org.glassfish.resources.mail.naming.MailNamingObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(MailNamingObjectFactory.java:58)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:342)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:877)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:834)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:257)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.naming.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:189)
        at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.api.ResourceProxy.create(ResourceProxy.java:66)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:827)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:257)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiNamingObjectFactory.java:74)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiInitializationNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiInitializationNamingObjectFactory.java:90)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:603)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:573)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lambda$lookup$0(JavaURLContext.java:153)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookupOrCollectException(JavaURLContext.java:550)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:153)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:818)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:269)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:413)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:413)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:551)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:493)
        ... 56 more
```

I really need your help, I tried but nothing!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong JAR files, or a mixture of right and wrong.

Comment: Okay thanks, how can i solve it?  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
i have donr this in my pom.xml

Comment: You don't need the implementation as a dependency, only the interfaces, which you should set to provided. See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.mail/jakarta.mail-api/2.1.2